# Change the map location by the location change of other in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers

I try to change one map's location by the another's location so I need to set a callback function bonded to something like "locationChanges()". In that way I can set the location of the one respected to other. How could I do it in Open Layers API.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure about what you need, is it something like that?

```
map.events.on({
    'moveend': function(){
        another_map.zoomToExtent(map.getExtent());
    }
});
```